# While driving, my handbrake gets automatically engaged (maybe)

Tags: brakes, hyundai, handbrake, accent

I own a Hyundai Accent.

I drove it for around 800kms yesterday.

All was fine until I was close to my house.

I heard a noise coming from the rear wheel as if the wheel was stuck.

After a while, when I tried to stop the car and engage the parking brake, I found it was too loose.

I tried applying it again after awhile and found that the brake was too tight.

I have no clue as to what to do or what could be wrong.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: When you were driving around, did it decelerate faster than normal when you went of the throttle?

Comment: Yeah. it did decelerate faster Alex. But i kinda called the hyundai on raod assistance and they opened the rear wheel and as soon as they did that the brake pad just fell out of the drum. so now they have asked me to replace it.

Comment: It seems the problem is cos i drove out in the rain on mud and all and kinda parked the car with the hand brakes engaged. Since the brake pads were wet, they kinda latched onto the drum and this kinda occured repeatedly and ultimately it snaped. this is what the service person told me. Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: also they adviced me to leave the car on gear and not to use the handbrake after such wet spells.  so tis question can be considered solved but i dont know how to close it. my first question. sorry.